# How can I pass a variable inside a middleware with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, api

Hi I am trying to create my own and very simple api token middleware so I have the middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use App\ApiUser;

class ApiAuth
{

  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
      $api_user_count = ApiAuth::where('api_token', $request->api_token)->count();

      if($api_user_count > 0)
      {
          abort(403, "Auth failed");
      }
    
      return $next($request);
  }
}
```

And I have the controller where I use the middleware like this:

```
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('apiauth');
}
```

BUT I need to send the token inside the middleware because I need to check in the database if it exists, I wonder how can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need to pass a variable? the only variable you are using there is from the request

Answer (score 0):

there is third paramatere on handle function you can passed within :

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next,$var)
  {
      $api_user_count = ApiAuth::where('api_token', $request->api_token)->count();

      if($api_user_count > 0)
      {
          abort(403, "Auth failed");
      }
    
      return $next($request);
  }
```

this way to pass variable in middleware :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('apiauth:'.$var);
}
```

Comment: I wonder why the middleware is not aborting? I mean I send a empty variable and it should say Auth failed but it's not working, why do you think that it can happen? Thanks